# C# Mongo Filter Builder - nested array of objects - filter any docs where value of a specific property matches with one of the values in an array

Tags: c#, mongodb, filter, bson

I have a mongo collection (of `<BsonDocument>`) who could look like this:

```
{
  "someProperty1": "someValue1",
  "users": [
   { "name": "sampleuser@test.com", "displayName" : "Sample User" }
   { "name": "anotheruser@test.com", "displayName" : "Another User" }
  ]
},
  "someProperty2": "someValue2",
  "users": [
   { "name": "testuser@test.com", "displayName" : "Test User" },
   { "name": "anotheruser@test.com", "displayName" : "Another User" },
  ]
},
  "someProperty3": "someValue3",
  "users": [
   { "name": "anotheruser@test.com", "displayName" : "Another User" }
  ]
}
```

I want to filter with an IEnumerable of strings, that contains a set of `name` and want to get every document where at least one of the names in `users` is matching.

For example i would have Array `filterArray` with the following Value:

`["testuser@test.com", "sampleuser@test.com"]`

with this i want to build a FilterDefinition `filter` and after appling it:

`await mongoColletion.Find(filter).ToListAsync()`

It should have the following output (as `IEnumerable<BsonDocument>`):

```
[
  {
  "someProperty1": "someValue1",
  "users": [
     { "name": "sampleuser@test.com", "displayName" : "Sample User" }
     { "name": "anotheruser@test.com", "displayName" : "Another User" }
   ]
  },
  "someProperty2": "someValue2",
  "users": [
     { "name": "testuser@test.com", "displayName" : "Test User" },
     { "name": "anotheruser@test.com", "displayName" : "Another User" },
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I build this FilterDefinition?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$elemMatch` and `$in`

```
db.productList.find({
    users: {
        $elemMatch: { 
            name: {
                $in: ['newuser@test.com', 'sampleuser@test.com' ]
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In C#

```
var coll = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collection_name");
var result = coll.Find("{ users: { $elemMatch: {name: { $in: ['testuser@test.com', 'sampleuser@test.com' ] }  }  } }").ToList();
```

Or with Builder

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "sampleuser@test.com", "testuser@test.com" };
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.ElemMatch("users",
        Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.In("name", list));
```

Or with data model:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Model
{
    [BsonElement("users")]
    public User[] Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("displayName")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

You can use this filter with data model

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "sampleuser@test.com", "testuser@test.com" };
var filter = Builders<Model>.Filter.ElemMatch(m => m.Users, 
    Builders<User>.Filter.In(u => u.Name, list));
var coll = db.GetCollection<Model>("collection_name");
var result = coll.Find(filter).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it out by myself:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.AnyIn("users.name", filterArray);
```